# Credit Card Validator confusion

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time trying to understand what to do next.  I've gotten the code correct up until this point.  My instructions were to create a credit card validator without an array, we're a beginner computer science class and we haven't gotten to that point yet.  Here's my code. Whenever I compile the code it gives me the error:

"java:21: error:  method isValid in class CreditCardValidator cannot be applied to given types;
if (isValid(card)) {
   required: int, int, String
   found: String
   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
/**
   Credit Card Validator

   @author  Your Name
   @date    Today's Date
   @class   Our Class
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CreditCardValidator {

   public static void main (String[] args) {
      String card = "4012888888881881";

      // When you are finished writing the methods below,
      // uncomment the three lines below to test.

      // Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      // System.out.print("Enter a Credit Card Number: ");
      // String card = input.nextLine();

     if (isValid(card) ) {
         System.out.print("valid");
      } else {
         System.out.print("invalid");
         // If False, state the card number is invalid
     }
      // System.out.println(getDigit(18) + " should be 9 ");
      // System.out.println(getDigit(5) + " should be 5 ");
      //System.out.println(sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(card+ "should be 47"));
   }

   /** 
      Returns true if the card number is valid 

      To determine if a card is valid, the sum of the Double Even Place
      Numbers and the Sum of the Odd Place Numbers must be divisible by
      ten (10), the String must be 13 to 16 digits, *and* the String must
      start with "4", "5", "37", or "6".

      @param number: A 13 to 16 digit String of numbers

      @returns true if the String is a valid card, False otherwise
   */
   public static boolean isValid(int totalEven, int totalOdd, String company) {
        if (((totalEven + totalOdd) % 10 == 0) && company.equals("Visa")) {
          return true;
        } else {
            if (((totalEven + totalOdd) % 10 == 0) && company.equals("Master Card")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                if (((totalEven + totalOdd) % 10 == 0) && company.equals("American Express")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    if (((totalEven + totalOdd) % 10 == 0) && company.equals("Discover Card")) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
   }    
   /** 
      Double every second digit from *right to left*. 

      If doubling of a digit results in a two-digit number, add the two digits
      together to get a single digit number using the getDigit(...) method.

      Use a *loop* to cycle through all the numbers of the String.
      Note: You will need to *convert a char to an int*

      @param number: A 13 to 16 digit String of numbers

      @returns an integer
   */
   public static int sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(String number){
        int totalEven = 0;
        int start = number.length() - 1; // starts at 14
        // i = 14;  14 > 0;  14 -= 2
        for (int i = start; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            char c = number.charAt(i);
            int digit = Character.getNumericValue(c) * 2;
            // System.out.println(digit + " " + getDigit(digit));
            totalEven += getDigit(digit);
        }
    return totalEven; // Total of double even place
   }
   /**  
      Return this number if it is a single digit, otherwise, return the sum 
      of the two digits. For example, 18 will return 9 (because 1 + 8)
      @param number: a digit that will be between 0 and 18
      @returns an integer
   */
   public static int getDigit(int number){
     int calc = 0;
     if (number < 10) {
    // This is one digit
   } else {
       // This is two digits
        calc = number - 9;
   }
   return calc;
   }
   /** 
      Return sum of odd-place digits in number

      Use a *loop* to cycle through all the numbers of the String.
      Note: You will need to *convert a char to an int*

      @param number: A 13 to 16 digit String of numbers

      @returns an integer
   */
   public static int sumOfOddPlace(String number){
     int totalOdd = 0;
     int start = number.length();

     for (int i = start; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
         char c = number.charAt(i);
         int digit = Character.getNumericValue(c) * 2;

        totalOdd += getDigit(digit);
     }
    return totalOdd;
   }

   /** 
      Return the company of the card by looking at the character
      at the zero (0) index of number.

      @param number: A 13 to 16 digit String of numbers

      @returns a String that is either 
         "Visa", "Master Card", "American Express", or "Discover Card"
   */
   public static String getCompany(String number){
     int card = number.length();
     int i = card - number.length();
     char c = number.charAt(i);
     int digit = Character.getNumericValue(c);
     int d = i + 1;
    String company = "";

    if (digit == 4 ) {
      company = "Visa";
   } else if (digit == 5) {
       company = "Master Card";
   } else if (digit == 6) {
       company = "Discover Card";
   } else if (digit == 3 && d == 7) {
       company = "American Express";
   }
        return company;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the error means? Let me emphasize the declaration `isValid(int totalEven, int totalOdd, String company)`

Comment: Your `isValid()` method requires three arguments. You've only provided one here `if (isValid(card) ) {`

Answer (score 0):

The method signature is 
`public static boolean isValid(int totalEven, int totalOdd, String company)`

On line 21, you're calling it using 
`isValid(card)` where card is a String, "4012888888881881"

The error tells you exactly what is wrong. Without looking in much detail, I suspect you'll need to call sumOfOddPlace() and sumOfDoubleEvenPlace() first and use the results of those to call isValid()

If you're using an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ, it should flag this up in the editor

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding.  I'm using Notepad++.  The actual code was written by me, but my instructor gave us the skeleton and we were told to follow this format.  I'm still confused as to how I would display the actual type of credit card and the validity of it? Can you give me an example?

Comment: #1 Do yourself a favour and download an IDE, it'll make your life much easier. I recommend IntelliJ IDEA. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: #2 have a read of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html it should clear up your confusion around method arguments